# I'm Stuck on this Oracle Query ( Shows no data when run )

Tags: sql, database, oracle

so I'm trying to answer this query in my oracle database . I'm quite new to SQL.
My Query is to **List the full details of the cinemas managed by the employees with the employee number 52 and 55**.
I have the test data for this in both the employee and Cinema table which correlates with one another. 
However, when I run the statement it just shows the selected column names with no data . And when I run the script it says no rows selected. ( Even though I've commited my changes to my test data in both tables ).

Below is the code I've used.

```
SELECT Cinema.Cinema_no , Cinema.Cinema_Name , Cinema.Location , Cinema.Managerempno  
FROM CINEMA 
INNER JOIN employee ON Cinema.Cinema_no = employee.emp_no 
WHERE Cinema.Managerempno = '52' AND Cinema.Managerempno = '55' ;
```

Please let me know if I've gone completely wrong with this. Or whether I need to change something within it. Thank you

Comment: `WHERE Cinema.Managerempno in ('52', '55')`

Comment: Or `WHERE Cinema.Managerempno = '52' OR Cinema.Managerempno = '55'`.

Comment: Cinema no = employee no doesn’t look right

Comment: Also, your join condition seems a bit illogical. Seems rather strange to join the employee number on the cinema number. Shouldn't it be Cinema.Cinema_no = employee.Cinema_no or something like that? Just a guess, it depends on how your db look of course.

Comment: @Sharad Don't put a "solve' in the title to instruct your problem is now solve. Accept an answer bu checking the green check mark on the left of the most helpfull answer.

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond Oh Sorry about that , new to this website. WIll do that then.

Comment: @Sharad no problem. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
SELECT c.Cinema_no, c.Cinema_Name, c.Location, c.Managerempno  
FROM CINEMA c 
WHERE c.Managerempno IN (52, 55);
```

Notes:

- You don't need the `JOIN`.  The employee number is in the `Managerempno` column.
- Table aliases make queries easier to write and to read.
- `Empno` is -- presumably -- a number.  So, don't use single quotes around the constants.

Comment: Thank you , seems as if I was completely wrong with adding the Inner Join . But I had a vague idea about the where clause. My brain was going crazy for 2 hours thinking why it wasn't working.

Comment: @Sharad . . . You were not "completely wrong" in adding the inner join.  You simply made the query a bit more complicated than necessary.